# Sort values in a dataframe by a column and take second one only if equal

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, sorting

I've created a dataframe using random values using the following code:

```
values = random(5)
values_1= random(5)
col1= list(values/ values .sum())
col2= list(values_1)

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':col1, 'col2':col2})
df.sort_values(by=['col2','col1'],ascending=[False,False]).reset_index(inplace=True)
```

The dataframe created in my case looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, the dataframe is not sorted in descending order by 'col2'. What I want to achieve is that it first sorts by 'col2' and if any 2 rows have same values for 'col2', then it should sort by 'col1' as well. Any suggestions? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution almost working well, but if use `inplace` in `reset_index` it is not reused in `sort_values`.

Possible solution is add `ignore_index=True`, so `reset_index` is not necessary.

```
np.random.seed(2022)  
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':np.random.random(5), 'col2':np.random.random(5)})
df = df.sort_values(by=['col2','col1'],ascending=False, ignore_index=True)
print (df)
       col1      col2
0  0.499058  0.897657
1  0.049974  0.896963
2  0.685408  0.721135
3  0.113384  0.647452
4  0.009359  0.486988
```

Or if want use `inplace` add it only to `sort_values` and add also `ignore_index=True`:

```
df.sort_values(by=['col2','col1'],ascending=False, ignore_index=True,inplace=True)
print (df)
       col1      col2
0  0.499058  0.897657
1  0.049974  0.896963
2  0.685408  0.721135
3  0.113384  0.647452
4  0.009359  0.486988
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is correct but you've missed an inplace=True inside sort_values. Due to this, the sorting does not actually take place in your dataframe. Replace it with this:

```
df.sort_values(by=['col2','col1'],ascending=[False,False],inplace=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to also do the sort `inplace=True`, not only the `reset_index()`